# asp.net CurrentUICulture and resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, globalization, resx

In my asp.net app I want to let user to change his profile language and then load respective resx file.

I have two global .resx files:

`LocalizedText.resx`

`LocalizedText.pl.resx`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
      ...
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
           setUserSettings(...)
      }                       
}
```

and

```
private void setUserSettings(...)
{
    ...
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl");
}
```

`setUserSettings(...)` is used also when user changes his profile settings.

The problem is that it is always fallbacking to `LocalizedText.resx` file instead of loading `LocalizedText.pl.resx`

I debbuged it and CurrentUICulture is always "en_US" at the beginning of Page_Load.

I tried to set also UICulture and Culture properties but it didn't work.

When I use Page.Culture="auto" it loads .pl.resx file when I set my browser language to "pl" but it is not what I want.

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should override the Page `InitializeCulture` method and set `CurrentUiCulture` there.
For more info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx

Comment: it's kinda clue, but I try to set CurrentUiCulture also after user change his setting in drop-down, but InitializeCulture is raised autamaitcaly before SelectedIndexChanged event. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @pawlakppp: When user changes his language you can best send him to another url (ie: /pl/info.aspx). this way the InitializeCulture can pick the language from the url, and search engines can index all languages, instead of only the default language.

Comment: I think you can still use the InitializeCulture method for that, but you have to find the dropdownlist value in Page Request.Form["dropdownListId"]
See code example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Willem, Sven, wow nice ideas I'll try it tommorow at work. Many thanks :)